# C++ Program to calculate the percent win and loss after x amount of games

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program that will calculate the probabilities of winning and losing in the game craps. I got my code to "work", but the win/loss percent should be around ~50%, but I am always getting somewhere around 70-80% instead. I have spent a few hours looking for what I did wrong, and I cannot figure it out. I believe the error is somewhere in the function playGame.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int rollDice ();
bool playGame();


int main ()
{
  int number;
  bool outcome;
  int win =0;
  int lose =0;
  int roll;
  double winPercent;
  double losePercent;
  int track =0;

  srand(time(0));

  cout << "How many games do you want to play? : ";
  cin >> number;

  for (int x =0; x < number; x++)
    {
          track++;
      outcome = playGame();
      if(outcome ==true)
        win++;
      else
        lose++;
    }
  winPercent = (double)win/track*100;
  losePercent = (double)lose/track*100;


  cout << setw(8) << "win %" << setw(8) << "lose %" << endl;
  cout << setw(8) << fixed << setprecision(3) << winPercent  << setw(8) << losePercent << endl;

 return 0;

}

int rollDice()
{
  int roll;

  roll = (rand() % 6 + 1) + (rand() % 6 + 1);

  return roll;

}

bool playGame ()
{
  int roll;
  bool winner = true;
  int firstRoll;

  firstRoll = rollDice();

  if (firstRoll == 7 || firstRoll == 11)
      return winner;
  else if (firstRoll == 2 || firstRoll == 3 || firstRoll == 12)
      return winner = false;

  else
    {
     do
       {
         roll = rollDice();

       }while (roll != firstRoll && roll != 7 && roll != 2 && roll != 3 && roll != 3);
  if (roll == 7 || roll == 11 || roll == firstRoll)
      return winner;
  else
   return winner = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: => "roll != 3 && roll != 3"

Comment: I have no idea what "craps" is, but have you checked the logic of your program? It has some strange things like the do while, do you want the second role dice to repeat until both results are the same? (because that is what it does). The other conditions in the do while are unnecessary.  Also in the if, the first conditions are always false and the last one always true. so it always return a winner. Therefore the possibility of it being 50-50 doesnt seem true.

Comment: 3 out of 12 are false, the rest are true makes 3/12= 0.25 therefore the win % being 75% seems quite reasonable

Comment: Craps is a game where you win by rolling a 7 or 11 on the Come Out roll, or rolling the point twice.Lose by rolling a 2, 3, or 12 on the Come Out roll, or rolling a 7 before rolling the point twice.

Comment: And what do you mean 3 of the 12 are false? I am looking at it and I do not see what you mean by that.

Comment: I'd suggest putting print commands in for each roll, at least temporarily, then you can step through and see that the logic isn't doing anything wrong.

Comment: also you don't need "return winner = false;" get rid of "winner" completely and return true or false.

Comment: you didn't put roll != 12 in your last test, you put roll != 3 twice